# Terminated due to code signing error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, code-signing

OK, this is driving me crazy and I would *really* appreciate it if someone could help me debug this:

- I'm using Xcode 6.1 (<del>6A1042b</del> 6A1046a) on OSX Yosemite 10.10 (14A361c)
- I have 2 valid certificates in my keychain (Distribution/Installer)

**General Tab**

[image: General Panel]

**Build Settings**

[image: Build Settings]

**When running the app**

[image: Terminated due to code signing error]

Help! What's going on?

---

P.S. For some reason, after having selected "Mac App Store" and setting my Signing Identities as shown, the "Signing" in the General tab automatically drops back to "None". If I revert it to "Mac App Store", "Debug" and "Release" switch to some generic "Mac Developer".

---

**UPDATE** (That's what the logs show)

```
EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
```

Comment: I have the same problem.  Did you find a solution?  I switched to a new iMac recently so I'm wondering if that is part of it.  Never had this problem in the past though.

Comment: @TyJacobs Actually what I did was to switch from Yosemite to Mavericks as my development machine and... boom, it worked! Don't ask me why... As it always happens with code signing and certificates (at least for me), it's not an exact science : You do whatever comes to your head and at some point, for some yet unknown reason, it works... lol

Comment: Hi....kameleon....i get same issue.did you get solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you set up your Mac, either from a time machine backup or as a fresh install, unless you properly backed up your certificates and migrated them over to your new machine you MUST create new certificates.  Do it from the beginning.  Do not use the certificates you created for Mavericks in Yosemite or on a new machine.  If you recreate new certificates it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can RUN your mac system in below steps.**

- Set "provisional profile" as "None" and "code signing identity" as "Don't code sign" in "Build setting"
- Set "signing" as "None" in "General"
  Please refer attached screen shot.
  [image]

[image]

**You can submit "app store" OR "identity developer" in below steps.**

- Set "Provisional profile" and "Code Signing identity" in build settings.
- Code "signing" as "None"
- Configure your apple account in xcode.(Xcode->preference->Account->add apple account).
- Archive your application and submit or provide build as identifier developer.(product->Archive)

Please refer attached screen shot.
[image]